# Editing PNG file

Tags: png

I've inherited a PNG file that I'd like to edit. It contains graphics and text elements. I've tried to select different elements (such as text box) but nothing will activate. Can anyone help. I do have the file if someone would like to take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

The only way a PNG file would behave as you seem to wish it to is if it were a "fireworks" png. That is, saved to disk by fireworks. That software uses a proprietary way to save png's and it is the only widely available application to do so.

In any other case you likely have what's called a "flat" png, in which you can not select elements, just pixels. Depending on the complexity of the image, you might be best off:
1: Asking for the source file from the one who gave you this image.
2: Recreating it in graphics software of your choice.
3: Get someone else to perform step 2.

Comment: Yup, it must be a flat PNG. I'll go digging for the source file. It's too busy of a graphic to recreate it. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to change. If just the text, then you can chop that out of the original (if it is possible), find a replacement font to buy, and redesign it. It would probably be better than hacking on something forever.